# How to post data from dropdown to filter table in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm printing CSV file on a webpage, the following code reads the file from the directory and displays data in table format this part works really well.

But I need to filter this table with the help of two dropdowns one has session id and the second one is the start date.

The problem is I'm not able to pass the value from these two dropdowns to the the `if ($v[0] != $session && $row > 0) continue;` where `$v[] may have index 0 or 1` and `$session` has value from dropdowns.

```
    <?php
    $dir = 'uploads/';
    $files = scandir($dir);
    ?>
    <form name="form1" method="post">
            <select class="form-control col-sm-5" onChange="document.forms['form1'].submit()" id="chooseterm" name="chooseterm">
                <option value="" selected>Choose Term</option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($files as &$value) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
    <?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $t = $_POST["chooseterm"];
        $filepath = "uploads/$t";
        $row = 0;
        $the_big_array = [];
        $unique_start_date = [];
        $unique_ids = array();
        if (($h = fopen("{$filepath}", "r")) !== false) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
                $the_big_array[] = $data;
                $unique_ids[$data[0]] = true;
                $unique_start_date[$data[1]] = true;
            }
            fclose($h);
        }
    ?>



    <select class="form-control col-sm-5" onChange="document.forms['form1'].submit()" id="choosessionid" name="choosessionid">
            <?php foreach ($unique_ids as $k => $v) {echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $k . '</option>';}?>
    </select>

    <select class="form-control col-sm-5" onChange="document.forms['form1'].submit()" id="session_start_date" name="session_start_date">
            <?php foreach ($unique_start_date as $k => $v) {echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $k . '</option>';}?>
    </select>

    </form>

    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <?php
            array_shift($the_big_array);
            $temp = '';
            foreach ($the_big_array as $k => $v) {
                if (isset($_POST['choosessionid']) || ($_POST['session_start_date']) ) {
    $session_start_date = '';
    $session = '';
    if (isset($_POST['choosessionid'])){
        $session = $_POST['choosessionid'];
        if ($v[0] != $session && $row > 0) continue;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['session_start_date'])){
        $session = $_POST['session_start_date'];
        if ($v[1] != $session && $row > 0) continue;
    }
} //at $session I need values from dropdown choosessionid OR session_start_date else show all the results 

                $row++;      
        ?>
        <?="<tr>"; ?>
        <?="<td>" . $v[0] . "</td>"; ?>
        <?="<td>" . $v[1] . "</td>"; ?>
        <?="<td>" . $v[2] . "</td>"; ?>
        <?="<td>" . $v[3] . "</td>"; ?>
        <?="</tr>"; ?>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php    
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: You can use jquery datatable to filter it : https://datatables.net

Comment: I dont want to use any library

Comment: I can see in your code you gave name and id for both dropdown as "choosessionid" and you did'nt define "session_start_date" .

Comment: ohh typo here..